# How can I track down the source of a transitive dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, dependency-management

In a project/solution with lots of `<PackageReference>` dependencies, it can be difficult to find the source of a transitive dependency that's being pulled in. For example, no projects in my solution directly reference the package System.Data.SqlClient, but something is pulling it in transitively. Tracking that down "by hand" is virtually impossible in a large solution or project with lots of direct package references.

Is there any ready-made way (eg, a combination of .Net CLI commands) that, given a particular package, will find and reveal the source of the transitive reference? I use Rider, which has some awesome code navigation and "discovery"-type tools, but I can't find anything that helps with my goal.

Note: I also have VisualStudio if it has this capability built-in somewhere, I'd just need a pointer to where/how.

Answer (score 31):

A [custom tool](https://github.com/bjorkstromm/depends) called `dotnet depends` is great for viewing reverse dependencies.

- Installation: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-depends`
- Usage: `dotnet depends .\MyProject.csproj`

[NuGet 6.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/announcing-nuget-6-3-transitive-dependencies-floating-versions-and-re-enabling-signed-package-verification/#view-transitive-dependencies-in-visual-studio) in Visual Studio also shows this if you hover over the transitive package.
[image: Hovering over shows the source of the transitive package]

Comment: Be aware that currently the Transitive Packages are only shown (and appear only in the search) if nuget version > 6.3 (Visual Studio 2022 17.3+) is used and nuget displays one Project (not the Project Solution / not within the multi Project Package View).

Comment: I get "Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element" when I try to use this in my project.

Comment: The part of "hover over transitive package" is the best answer!!!

Answer (score 22):

Searching in VS did not work for me, at least not for a BCL package like System.Net.Http. What did work is looking in **obj\project.assets.json**, which lists all dependencies.

It's a manual process of searching for each package up the tree: find your target package under the `"dependencies"` node of another package, e.g.:

```
      "Some.Other.Package/1.0.0": {
        ...
        "dependencies": {
          ...
          "System.Net.Http": "4.3.4"
        }
      }
```

... then repeat for that package ("Some.Other.Package" in this example) until you get to one that is directly referenced.

There is code to automate this at https://github.com/jerriepelser-blog/AnalyzeDotNetProject but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 21):

The capability is built into the latest Visual Studio 2019.

With Visual Studio 2019, Update 6, I can see something like the following:

[image: Solution explorer dependencies tree]

Note that you can also discover packages by searching in the solution explorer.

[image: Solution explorer search]

Unfortunately it's not available in the NuGet Package Manager installed view yet.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't think it's quite comprehensive because, for the specific package I'm trying to track down, it doesn't show any reference except in a project that isn't a dependency of the one I'm researching.

Comment: I'm not following. 

How do you know that there's a reference to a package then? 
Note that packages can come in through project references too.

Comment: I know because I can use classes from the package. And yes, I'm aware of project references bringing in transitive dependencies, too. That's part of what makes finding them so tricky.

Comment: Can you look at your project.assets.json file? The SolutionExplorer looks at that as the source of truth. Happy to peek at it if you can share the content. Keep in mind it might contain some PII info in the form of PATs and package names.

On the other hand, does search not help?

Comment: Can't fathom why, but this list was incomplete, where [`dotnet depends` was not](/a/75992617).

Comment: @imps - you know there's a reference to a package because, for example, some external scanner (e.g. Trivy) identifies it as a vulnerability.  The problem here is not finding transitive dependencies in a single project, it's finding them in a solution that may have 10s of projects.

Answer (score 3):

Since I had the same problem and didn't find anything working (on SO, google and my installed VS2022 Ultimate), I've create a powershell and python script.

The script uses the `nuget-deps-tree` - npm package to get a dependency tree and then traverses this tree to find the nuget.

See: https://github.com/Kraego/NailDownNuget

Answer (score 1):

I have [DependencyVisualizerTool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DependencyVisualizerTool/) that can show you the full dependency graph for a given project.
For example, for a restore project, it can do the following:

- Project(blue) App depending on project Lib (blue), and package with a Vulnerability Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3. (white means package, red border means vulnerable)
- It also shows, project Lib (blue) depending on a deprecated package Nuget.Core 2.14.0 (yellow)
- Finally, it shows NuGet.Core depending on Microsoft.Web.XDT 2.1.0.

[image]

Comment: That output looks fantastic and super useful. I'm no longer working in .Net so I can't really accept the answer in good faith (I can't try it out), but this looks quite promising for future readers.

Comment: I tried this and I couldn't figure out how to view the diagram.... is that something you have to have visual studio to view?

Comment: You need Visual Studio's DGML viewer yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution in many cases but just to mention it. Switching to [paket dependency manager](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/index.html) could help as well, especially for bigger projects.
It has a command called [paket why](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-why.html) that quickly tells you for each package whether it's a top level, a direct or a transient dependency and additionally shows the dependency chain. See [this](https://theimowski.com/blog/2016/10-30-paket-why-command/index.html) blog post for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

**VS code + dotnet:**

build your application `dotnet build` then go to obg -> project.assests.json.

Then you will see the following similar structure

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/1.2.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal": "1.2.0",
          "something": "1.2.0",
     ,}
}
```

In this example the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` is the top level package, and  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal` is the the depeinacy.

Note also that the might also that the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal` might be a top level dep for another dep

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of the answer posted almost 2 years ago by @EMO.