# How to find root dependency of restored nuget package?

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I can see some restored packages in the packages folder of the project but they seem to be indirect dependencies as they can not be seen in .csproj or package.config files. I wanted to know the root dependency of these packages they are causing some alerts regarding vulnerabilities. Is there a way to find it?

Tried checking in project.assets.json, .csproj, package.config files. Was expecting to see the restored package somewhere in these.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75109631/11473934